# initialization class based on array

Tags: c++

I constructed a class integer based on an array with fixe compiled size, (it really looks like c11 std::array). I am looking to integrate a new constructor based on the ideology of array.
I mean

```c++
integer<128> = {64-bit number, 64-bit number};
// as
int a[2] = {1,1};
```

Well  I have to overload the operator= something like

```c++
template<int NumBits>
class integer{
     typedef boost::uint64_t      value_type;
     static const std::size_t numwords = (NumBits+63)/64;

    value_type& operator[](size_type i);
    const value_type& operator[](size_type i) const;

integer & operator= ("What do I write {...}"){
    container[0] = ????        
    container[1] = ????        
    .................
} 

    value_type container[numwords];
};
```

Comment: You should check out [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list).

Comment: how is `uint64_t` indexable?

Comment: oups, I updated my post. I'm checking std::initializer_list, it sounds good.

Comment: I am new on this forum, I do not know all options, I am looking

Comment: All these options, more than boost ^_^

Comment: Look at how std::array is implemented: it doesn't need any special constructor for the {} syntax to work, as an aggregate.

Comment: For the aggregate I can not. I have 2 constructors into my class

Comment: Note that `int a[2] = {1,1};` does **not** invoke `operator=`.

Comment: yes it is an aggregate, I am going to a solution based on std::initializer_list.